# Select and join error must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT *,
case when SUM(fld_allocated_time) / 24 < fld_allocated_days 
then 'OK'
else 'NOK' 
end as Alocated
from
(
SELECT tbl_project.fld_id, tbl_project.fld_allocated_days, 
tbl_project_timesheet.fld_allocated_time 
FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project
INNER JOIN "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet
ON tbl_project.fld_id=tbl_project_timesheet.fld_id
) AS Alias
```

and I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR: column "total.fld_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> SQL state: 42803
> Character: 8
> ```

tbl = table
fld = column
SD_PRJ = schema name

Comment: that script can't generate that error.   there is no "total.fld_id" in the script that I can see.   Unless there is a trigger on one of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate a single sum for all the rows of your query and compare it with fld_allocated_days in each row then you can try this:

```
with Alias as (
SELECT * from (
    SELECT tbl_project.fld_id, tbl_project.fld_allocated_days, 
           tbl_project_timesheet.fld_allocated_time 
    FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project
         INNER JOIN "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet
         ON tbl_project.fld_id=tbl_project_timesheet.fld_id
)
select a.*, 
       case when b.sm < fld_allocated_days then 'OK' else 'NOK' end as Alocated
from Alias a cross join
    (select SUM(fld_allocated_time) / 24 sm from Alias) b;
```

However, I suppose you need something like this:

```
SELECT tbl_project.fld_id,
       case when SUM(tbl_project_timesheet.fld_allocated_time) / 24 
                 < fld_allocated_days 
            then 'OK' 
            else 'NOK' 
       end as Alocated
FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project
     INNER JOIN "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet
     ON tbl_project.fld_id=tbl_project_timesheet.fld_id
GROUP BY tbl_project.fld_id, tbl_project.fld_allocated_days;
```

Comment: How can I make sum for rows from an input parameter (fld_project_id) ?
where fld_project_id = @parameter

Comment: @Alienware You need to calculate sum for each fld_project_id?

Comment: Let me tell you all the story,I have a stored procedure which insert in database allocation time for each employee from input parameters as allocated_time project_id etc..., and I need to add a new condition to verify if the new allocation time for project not exceeded the allocations. I received an input parameter project_id and I have 2 columns in 2 tables one for allocated days in table Project and one for allocated hours in table Project Timesheet

Comment: @Alienware Ok, I got it. The second query in my answer seems to be what you need

Comment: I was thinking to SUM all rows with project_id let's say 22 and divided by 24 to compare it with fld_allocated_days from second table..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64268/discussion-between-alienware-and-multisync).

Answer (score 1):

Add rest of the column in select list to your `GROUP BY` like

```
) AS Alias
GROUP BY fld_id, fld_allocated_days, fld_allocated_time
```